# OPCUA connection machine message [NODE-OPCUA-E07] message size 108 exceeds the negotiated message size 0 nb chunks 1

Tags: opc-ua, node-opcua

when connecting to the machine, I get this error:
[NODE-OPCUA-E07] message size 108 exceeds the negotiated message size 0 nb chunks 1

I setup the connection this way

```
const connectionStrategy = {
     initialDelay: 1000,
     maxRetry: 1
}

const client = OPCUAClient.create({
     connectionStrategy: connectionStrategy,
     endpointMustExist: false,
});
```

Are there any parameters to configure?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter the transport settings like this:

```
const client = OPCUAClient.create({
     connectionStrategy: connectionStrategy,
     endpointMustExist: false,
     transportSettings: {
            maxChunkCount: 20,
            maxMessageSize: 8 * 8192, 
            receiveBufferSize: 8 * 1024,
            sendBufferSize: 8 * 1024
        });
```